# How to reduce the if else if statement and make it better?

Tags: c

I have to adjust the Float type Remaining count in the specific range as shown in the code, this works fine, but the issue is, if the Count is 10 or 20 or 30, there will be many if else if condition and that's very inefficient.

Below sample code is for adjusting upto 5 count.

Any suggestions how can I improve this?

Here it is :

```
  for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    RemainingCount[i] = (( (float) CurrentMaterialWeight[i] * (float)TotalMaterialCount[i]) / ( (float) TotalMaterialWeight[i]));   

    if (RemainingCount[i] <= 0.3)
     {
        AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = 0;
     }

    else if ( RemainingCount[i] > 0.50 &&  RemainingCount[i] <= 1.50)
    {
        AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = 1;
    }

    else if ( RemainingCount[i] > 1.50 &&  RemainingCount[i] <= 2.50)
    {
        AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = 2;
    }

   else if ( RemainingCount[i] > 2.50 &&  RemainingCount[i] <= 3.50)
    {
            AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = 3;
    }

    else if ( RemainingCount[i] > 3.50 &&  RemainingCount[i] <= 4.50)
    {
            AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = 4;
    }
}
    So on.....
```

Comment: Why do you skip from 0.3 to 0.5?

Comment: Reverse the order and get rid of the right side of `&&`.

Comment: You keep testing what you already know.

Comment: or just use `round`.

Comment: @user2357112 Just to make accurate adjustment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Any example?

Comment: @EugeneSh. if `0.5` rounds downwards.

Comment: Of `round`? Do you really need me for that?

Comment: @WeatherVane You can subtract some *epsilon*.

Comment: The interesting part is the one where you are casting stuff to `float`... what is the original type of these operands? If they are integer, you can normalize all of this test to the denominator and get rid of the whole floating point hassle.

Comment: If it's for some sort of exercise where you can't use a pre made round function, you could use truncation rules. `float someRandomFloat = 4.55f; int truncatedNo = someRandomFloat; float diff = someRandomFloat  - truncatedNo;`  should be pretty self explanatory from there to write code that will scale.

Answer (score 0):

All if conditions can be replaced with one round function.
http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-arithmetic-functions/c-round-function/
https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html

Answer (score 0):

Rounding should be the trick. The only issue is that your adjustment slightly differs from the built in rounding in that your conditions like  `if (..., f <= 1.5)` would "downround" the value `1.5` to `1`, whereas the built in rounding `round(1.5)` would round up to `2`.

If you adapt your logic such that `1.499999` is adjusted to `1`, but `1.5` is adjusted to `2`, than you could simply use `int adjustment = round(f)`.

If you need the logic exactly as you specified, i.e. that `1.5` is adjusted to `1`, but `1.51` is adjusted to `2`, then you can decrease the floating value (as less as possible) before rounding. So `round(1.5 - epsilon)` would then give `1`.
See the following code, which makes use of built in function `nextafter`, which can be used to reduce a float value in the least possible step width:

```
#include <math.h>

int getAdjustment(float f) {
        return round(nextafter(f, -INFINITY));
}

int main()
{
    float floatValues[9] = {.2,.3,.31,.5,1.5,1.51,2.5,2.51,3.5};
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        float f = floatValues[i];
        cout << f << " adjustment: " << getAdjustment(f) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.2 adjustment: 0
0.3 adjustment: 0
0.31 adjustment: 0
0.5 adjustment: 0
1.5 adjustment: 1
1.51 adjustment: 2
2.5 adjustment: 2
2.51 adjustment: 3
3.5 adjustment: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given you the logic for the code that can reduce the IF else statement. Understand the logic first. You can modify the code according to your own need.

```
int left, right;   // declare two integer

for()
{
RemainingCount[i] = (( (float) CurrentMaterialWeight[i] * (float)TotalMaterialCount[i]) / ( (float) TotalMaterialWeight[i]));   

 // divide it into two parts RemainingCount[i]= 20.5511;

 char buffer[50];
 sprintf(buffer, "%lf", value);
 sscanf(buffer, "%d.%d", &left, &right);
// use what ever way to divide the number
  // left = 20  right = 5511

  float leftplus = left + 0.5;
  float leftminus = left - 0.5;

     // LEFTplus = 20.5
     // LEFTminus = 19.5

  if ( your_number <= leftsplus && your_number > leftminus  )
  {   //     20.55 <= 20.5      &&       20.55 > 19.5
    AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = LEFT;
   }else{ //  20.55
          AdjustedRemainingCount[i] = left +1;  // 21
             }


  }
```